# How to define a character set for credentials in pysftp?

Tags: python, ssh, character-encoding, pysftp

I'm trying to download a file from remote server. For that I need to define 'charset=ASCII' (I tried in FileZilla client). Then only connection gets success and I can view files. Else I get *'Authentication error'* from client end (using FileZilla client)

I'm using pysftp library to connect same remote server in my Python program;

```
 connOption = pysftp.CnOpts()
 connOption.hostkeys = None
    srv = pysftp.Connection(host=host, username=username, password=password, port=port, cnopts=connOption)
```

I don't know how to define `Charset` parameter here. There is no charset parameter for connection method.

How should I do this with pysftp?

> paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.

My username contains `_` and `’` characters. I just copy it from one source,

eg: `xxxxx_O’xxxxx`

Success attempt from FileZilla:

```
Status: Connecting to xxxxx...
Status: Connected to xxxx
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Status: Listing directory /
Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
```

Log file output:

```
2019-10-15 16:57:04 4480 1 Status: Connecting to xxxx...
2019-10-15 16:57:04 4480 1 Response: fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
2019-10-15 16:57:04 4480 1 Command: open "xxxx_O’xxxx@xxxxx" 22
2019-10-15 16:57:06 4480 1 Command: Trust new Hostkey: Once
2019-10-15 16:57:06 4480 1 Command: Pass: *********************
2019-10-15 16:57:06 4480 1 Status: Connected to xxxxxxx
2019-10-15 16:57:06 4480 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing...
2019-10-15 16:57:06 4480 1 Command: pwd
2019-10-15 16:57:06 4480 1 Response: Current directory is: "/"
2019-10-15 16:57:06 4480 1 Command: ls
2019-10-15 16:57:06 4480 1 Status: Listing directory /
2019-10-15 16:57:07 4480 1 Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
```

Comment: did you check in `pysftp.CnOpts` if there is no option `charset` ?

Comment: @furas, it supports only ciphers,hostkeys..I dont see option to define a charset. DO you know what parameter it is?

Comment: no, I don't know - I only try to guess where they could hide option like `charset` or `encode`.

Comment: @furas no none is defined like that in pysftp.CnOpts()  or pysftp.Connection()

Comment: So you have non-ascii characters in your username or password?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have a ' in my username. when i copy that to a notepad it looks bit different than typing '.

Comment: So please say that in your question.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I provided my username as I copied from the source. Forget about xxxx characters.Any help would be appriciated. It is a 3rd party server/client's. Im struggling with this for 2 days

Comment: Can you post your FileZilla log file?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I provided in the question. is that enough?

Comment: No. Log **file** please - not a copy of the messages log from GUI.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl added log file output

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify the password using bytes literal:

```
password=b"xxxxx_O’xxxxx"
```

---

Btw, SFTP/SSH protocol mandates a use of UTF-8 encoding. If your server uses a different encoding, then it is broken. And you should definitely not use non-ASCII usernames on such server (and using such usernames even on UTF-8 capable server is questionable).

Though ASCII encoding does not have the `’` character anyway. So ultimately the problem is probably that your username actually does not contain `’`, but whatever FileZilla (and the software that created the account) converted the `’` to.

Comment: I did same..but didnt work either. I got new username witout all those characters. Now working. fine

Comment: You would have to find out what is the real username as the server sees it. It probably is not with `’`, but with another character. – But getting a new username is the right way anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with pysftp. Please try this.

First, get host key from sftp server:

```
ssh-keyscan example.host.com | grep "ssh-rsa" > sftpserver01.pub
```

Python code:

```
def download_files_from_sftp(input_subdir):
    cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
    cnopts.hostkeys = cnopts.hostkeys.load('{}/sftpserver01.pub'.format(pubkeys_dir))   

    logging.info('I:--START--:--Download files from sftp--')

    try:
        with pysftp.Connection(host=hostname, username=username, password=password, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
            sftp.cwd(sftpin_input_dir)
            for file_name in sftp.listdir():
                if not file_name.startswith('.'):
                    local_file_path = '{}/{}'.format(local_input_dir, file_name)
                    sftp.get(file_name, local_file_path)
            sftp.close()
        logging.info('O:--SUCCESS--:--Download files from sftp--')
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info('O:--FAIL--:--Download files from sftp--:errorDesc/{}'.format(e))
        raise
```

Comment: I get still same autentication error. As i told in my orginal question, I need to define charset.  In Filezilla, without passing any host key, by defining the charset my connection is success

Comment: connOption.hostkeys  = connOption.hostkeys.load('sftpserver01.pub')

Comment: Can you access sftp server directly from command prompt without using Filezilla? For example command: `sftp username@host.ip`

Comment: In that case I get Permission denied, please try again. response. Only throw filezilla client by defining charset=ASCii, i can connect succefully

Comment: Are you using FileZilla client through HTTP proxy server? If not please contact an administrator, because your account or IP address could not access sftp server.

Comment: No , there is no any proxy server. As i Said, setting charset is additional I do in filezilla. How i can do that in pysftp is my original quetsion

Comment: There is no option in pysftp for setting a charset. Pysftp acts as a command line.